# Should Affordable Care Act be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

What is the rule for Affordable Care Act or affordable care act?

Comment: In what style have you seen it? What references to it have you found? Do you think they are incorrect?

Comment: If you're talking about a part of British - or internationally, most British-based - law, and that wording is the proper name then it should always be capitalised…  Affordable Care Act would be exactly comparable to Elizabeth J. LaHaise

Comment: In general, the congressionally-assigned name of a bill is written with initial caps.  It is treated as a "proper name".

Answer (score 2):

The government website of the U.S. Department of health and human services capitalizes "Affordable Care Act", and I would follow their lead.

https://www.hhs.gov/healthcare/about-the-aca/index.html